# Different email headers when registering new users

Tags: email

## Edited Question

I have a customer registration form with an **additional field** to fill in a **group**.

Depending on this field, the user should get one or another email.

## Original Question:

*I need some way to identify users, then to manually define them in a group, so I need to have different headers to be seen what the user wants in the group, and what not
how i can do this?
Thanks*

Comment: Question is not clear ,please elaborate

Comment: Your old version of the post was more understandable.

Comment: I need to be notified by users who want to be part of one group or another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## rewrite `sendNewAccountEmail` method

the "new account email" is sent here: `\Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::sendNewAccountEmail`. So you can rewrite the customer model, exchange this method and check inside the method whatever you want, and then send the one or the other mail.

## use an event

There is for sure an event you can use for this, but I didn't saw a way to suppress the automatic mail sending. So if you solve this problem, I think you are better with using an event.